# Existence of $\mathbb{Q}$ isomorphism

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Let $\alpha\in\Bbb{C}$ algebraic, root of $X^5+2X+6$. The question is exist a $\Bbb{Q}$-isomorphism $\sigma:\Bbb{Q}(\alpha) \to \Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha ^{-1}$?

I know this is false (I cheked its roots in Maple), and I know that it is true only if $\alpha ^{-1}$ is root of the polynomial too, but how I solve this in an exam? I couldn't find the roots. How do you solve this type of exercises?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to find the minimal polynomial for $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ and check whether it is the same polynomial. Since $\alpha^5 + 2\alpha + 6 = 0$ see what you can do to this equation to get a polynomial in terms of $\frac{1}{\alpha}$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it!, multiplying by $\frac{1}{6}X^{-5}$, $X^{-5}+\frac{1}{3}X^{-4}+\frac{1}{6}$ irreducible, degree equal to the extension and $\alpha^{-1}$ root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(X)=X^5+2X+6$ and note that $f$ is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ since $f$ is irreducible (it's 2-Eisenstein). If  $\sigma(\alpha)=1/\alpha$ then $f(1/\alpha)=0$ as well. Hence
$$
\alpha^5f(1/\alpha)=1+2\alpha^4+6\alpha^5=0,
$$
so you now have $\alpha^5=-(1+2\alpha^4)/6$. But you also know, since $f(\alpha)=0$, that $\alpha^5=-(2\alpha+6)$. Equating these, you can find a degree 4 polynomial whose root is $\alpha$, contradicting the fact that $\alpha$ has degree $5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.